# Problema com acentuação ao inserir dados em SQLite android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Estou tentando dá um `insert` em uma tabela, porém ele dá erro de sintaxe. Acredito que seja por causa do acento, mas mesmo pesquisando não conseguir resolver.

Erro no log:

> 11-19 00:34:52.959: W/AQuery(21157):
>   reporting:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "água": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE into noticia
>   (noticia_id, conteudo, titulo, resumo, imagem, data) VALUES (10228, 'A
>   Chapada Diamantina reserva verdadeiros monumentos naturais para
>   aqueles que se aventuram em seus caminhos: algumas das mais altas e
>   belas cachoeiras do Brasil estão por aqui, como uma recompensa, no fim
>   da trilha, pelo esforço dos viajantes. Deslumbre-se com a imponência
>   das dez maiores quedas dágua da região, em imagens selecionadas pelo
>   Guia.

*Insert* no código:

```
String query = "INSERT OR REPLACE into noticia (noticia_id, conteudo, titulo, resumo, imagem, data) VALUES (" + n.getId() + ", '" + n.getPost_content().replaceAll("’", "")
            + "', '" + n.getPost_title() + "', '" + n.getPost_excerpt().replaceAll("’", "") + "', '" + n.getImagem() + "', '" + n.getPost_modified() + "');";

    mDb.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: Creio que no lugar do `replaceAll("’", "")` deveria ser `replaceAll("'", "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente está tendo um injeção no seu sql, vi que você usou dágua, será que no texto não está d'água? pois se estiver dessa forma o problema está ai, essa aspa está fechando o parametro de conteúdo e esta sofrendo injeção no seu sql.

A melhor forma de resolver e a mais adequadra seria usar os próprios método que a classe SQLiteDatabase disponibiliza.

SQLiteDatabase possui métodos de CRUD, é muito mais interessante utiliza-los e em vez de concatenar dessa forma que vc está fazendo use contentValues, de uma pesquisada sobre isso.

Comment: Sim a palavra é d'água, está dágua porque eu já tinha retirado essa "'".